# .htaccess replace url parameter "name"

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL that will be something like

```
http://example.com/shake/pokladna/?id=35601-JILOSRO&name=Jilo%20s.r.o.&address=Hrušková%202194&city=Sokolov&zipcode=35601
```

I want to redirect that address to these (I need to replace "name" with "name_gls")

```
http://example.com/shake/pokladna/?id=35601-JILOSRO&name_gls=Jilo%20s.r.o.&address=Hrušková%202194&city=Sokolov&zipcode=35601
```

Is this code ok?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  (.*)&?name=(.*)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^pokladna/?$  $0?%1name_gls=%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Where are you putting that code? Do the URL parameters vary? Is `name` always an _internal_ URL parameter? Or could it also appear at the start of the query string?

Comment: I putting that code to .htaccess. Yes, URL parameters are vary. Third party API give me back these parameters. I am not sure if it will not to be changed in the future.

Comment: But where is the `.htaccess` file? I would have assumed it was the `.htaccess` file in the document root, however, your code suggests it is in the `/shake` subdirectory? This might be intentional, however, it could also be an error?

Comment: WordPress root directory

Comment: And where is your "WordPress root directory"?!

Comment: In http://example.com/shake/

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  (.*)&?name=(.*)? [NC]
> RewriteRule ^pokladna/?$  $0?%1name_gls=%2 [R=301,L]
> ```

This is close, but not quite correct. As stated, these directives are in the WordPress `.htaccess` file located at `/shake/.htaccess`. These directives need to go *before* any existing WP directives, if not already.

The `RewriteRule` *substitution* requires a slash prefix to make a valid external redirect in a per-directory `.htaccess` file. As it stands, the `$0` backreference excludes the slash prefix, so results in a relative path substitution - in which case the directory-prefix is added back, resulting in an invalid redirect.

Another potential problem is the *optional* `&` in the *CondPattern*, ie. the `&?` in `(.*)&?name=(.*)?`. On the given example URL, this will work OK, however, since the preceding `(.*)` is *greedy*, this will also match any query string parameter name that just **ends in "name"**. For example, a query string of the form `id=123&anothername=foo` would be changed to `id=123&anothername_gls=foo` - which I doubt is desirable. A way around this is to use *alternation*, eg. `(^|.+&)` to match either the start of the query string *or* a preceding URL param (and param delimiter).

I would also question the use of the `NC` flag on the `RewriteCond` directive - should this really be a case-insensitive match?

And you've made the trailing slash on the URL-path optional. Is this really optional? If it is then you should instead make sure this is canonicalised in the *substitution*. In the code below, I assume the trailing slash is mandatory, since it is present in your example.

With your specific example you will also need the `NE` (`noescape`) flag to prevent the %-encoded spaces (ie. `%20`) in the query string being doubly encoded.

So, bringing these points together, try something like the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|.+&)name=(.*)
RewriteRule ^pokladna/$  /$0?%1name_gls=%2 [NE,R,L]
```

Note that this is a temporary (302) redirect. Change the `R` to `R=301` only when you are sure it's working OK. Permanent redirects can make testing problematic, as they are cached hard by the browser.

Consequently, you will need to make sure the browser cache is cleared before testing.

And, as mentioned above, these must go *before* the existing WordPress directives (specifically, *before* the front controller).

Comment: How can I replace multiple paremeters?

Comment: @EscapeNetscape That would really depend on the requirements. If the multiple parameters are on the same request you'd need to recursively rewrite the URL first before triggering an external redirect (to avoid multiple redirects). This would warrant its own question.